# All pods to receive requests

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod

In a k8s cluster where there are 2 or more replicas of a specific pod.

I have the scenario where an event is fired from a different pod when a file is updated.

This event notifies the deployment of this update via an HTTP request. The pod should then take various actions.

The issue being since the deployment has multiple instances running how would one ensure every pod is notified of the update?

Currently to work around the issue, I scale down to one perform the update. Then scale up, this works fine but ideally I should be able to update the file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need an event system? 1 producer many subscribers

Comment: I see what you are saying, have the pod subscribe. The current architecture has a separate event listener and distributes these events via http. So you would rather have the pod itself listening for this specific event?

Comment: ye... for that you need an event system like rabbitMQ or SQS or some flavour

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour may be due to timeout issues. Try adding these parameters to your Ingress file in helm charts.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 32k
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: "8"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "86400"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "86400"
```